# request.GET.get can not read the full request on a search bar in a django app

Tags: django

I have a problem with the search bar in my django app, when i type a sentence, trying to look for an item, it interprets the sentence as a single name.
For example i have two items ( shirt and sweatshirt ) , when i type 'shirt sweatshirt' in the search bar, it says that this item isn't available. I there any way i could fix this problem?
this is the function that implements the request in my views file:

```
def search(request):
    try:
        q = request.GET.get('q')
    except:
        q = None
    if q:
        item = Item.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=q))
        context = {'query': q, 'item': item}
        template = 'results-page.html'

    else:
        template = "home-page.html"
        context = {}

    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: Search like this will only return items whicj title containes "shirt sweatshirt". Not sure what are you trying to do but django + postresql full text search could help you.

Comment: I want to display the items containing the term 'shirt' or the term 'sweatshirt' in their names.

Comment: You can split by spaces and do separatee query for each part and then join results

Comment: could you please provide me with more details please?

Comment: Something like this: https://gist.github.com/jangia/914782ffaac48498788d631a041b0692